# Why custom colors without scale_fill_identify does not work in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to understand, why my graph shows appropriately when scale_fill_identity is used ?

```
ggplot(data = result, aes(x = date, y = diffinPercentages)) + geom_col(  aes(fill= cond)) + scale_fill_identity()
```

[image]
If I leave out scale_fill_identity, then the graph does not show custom colors. Instead, ggplot makes up color of its own

```
   ggplot(data = result, aes(x = date, y = diffinPercentages)) + geom_col(  aes(fill= cond))
```

[image]
What does scale_fill_identify do to make sure custom colors are properly shown?

Comment: The `scale_fill_...` functions determine the scale used for the `fill` aesthetic, which would be the color used. If you don't include it, it uses the default ggplot color scale. By providing a `scale_fill_...` function, you replace the default color scale with one of your choice

Comment: Thanks. Would you mind answering instead of writing as a comment this so that I can accept your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `scale_fill_...` functions determine the scale used for the fill aesthetic, which would be the color used. If you don't include it, it uses the default ggplot color scale.

By providing a `scale_fill_...` function, you replace the default color scale with one of your choice –